# How SSG works in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, nuxt.js

I am new to the Nuxt development platform, having worked mostly in Vue(v2).

Having delved into the docs and experimenting locally for a bit there are a few things I still require clarity on:

1. In static generation mode, does each page its get its own Vue app instance? That is, every pre-rendered page that is requested from the server behave as an SPA on the client.
2. If #1 is true, does every page, and in effect, every app run isolated from all other pages and apps? No shared state?
3. When using Vuex in SSG mode, does each page get its own Vuex store that is inflated with an initial state while rendering the page on the server? And, does this state get passed down to the client?
4. This store is destroyed on navigating to a different page (or even refreshing the current page), to be replaced by a new one right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In SSG, every page is rendered ahead of time but at the end, will be hydrated and hence become an SPA. Nuxt is basically Vue on steroids but it's still Vue.
2. Not sure what you call isolated here, you can totally pass props, use emit etc... Meanwhile yeah, if you do have pages, they are not all loaded at the same time, there is code splitting + lazy loading + prefetching. Some info can be [found here](https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components#lazy-loading-your-components).
3. You can have [namespaced modules](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#modules) out of the box when using Vuex with Nuxt. You do have [`nuxtServerInit`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) to pre-populate the store yes. You could give a read to the [Nuxt lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#nuxt-lifecycle) btw. But you don't have a Vuex module by page out of the box, there is no real usage for this IMO. And yeah, you'll get your Vuex store on the client of course.
4. If you navigate to a different path with a `<a></a>` tag, you will nuke your SPA yeah. If you're using [`<nuxt-link></nuxt-link>`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtlink-component), you'll stay in the SPA since the Vue router will make the "navigation". But yeah, if you type a path directly into the url and press `Enter` or refresh the page with `F5`, your entire SPA will be nuked and **everything** will be replaced from the ground up.

I've [spoken at the latest Nuxt-nation](https://youtu.be/Q8ze3EiOvps), the quality is not amazing (sorry for this) but you could maybe get some interesting things out of it.

Comment: @praet please update your answer than writing it in comments.

Comment: Regarding #4: When using NuxtLink, how does the page remain in SPA when navigation to another pre-rendered page creates a new Vue app instance? Does this not contradict #1?
Regarding #3: So Vuex is overkill for even for scenarios such as gated/authenticated pages in our app that require state  management?
The video you linked is very helpful, even a few minutes in, thanks.

Comment: @praet 1. When using SSG, all the routes are already known ahead of time, so you could disable JS and still see them. It is not a new Vue app instance btw, it mounts a component/page but nothing from scratch. Hydration happens once so no, it does not contradict. After the hydration, you stay in the SPA as with a typical Vue app. 3. Vuex can be useful in many ways, I'll need to known the use case a bit more to give an advice here. If you want to have some checks for your pages, you can use Vuex but also middlewares: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware#middleware-directory